# How can I bind deep child property of directive's scope?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My dear friends,

We can bind a scope property of a directive to the value of DOM attribute.

This works:

```
module.directive 'MyDirective', ->
  scope:
    directiveVar: '='
```

...

```
<div class='MyDirective' directive-var='parentVar'></div>
```

In example above we bind directive's `directiveVar` property to `parentVar` property of the parent scope.

This is a bi-directional binding, so if `directiveVar` is changed `parentVar` is automatically updated, and vice versa.

**My question is:**

Is there a way I can bind a deep child property of my directive's scope instead? Like `scope.lv1.directiveVar` or `scope.lv1.lv2.lv3.directiveVar` instead of `scope.directiveVar`?

[Docs I read](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)

**What I want to achieve**

I have an object in directive scope named `lv1`. I want to bind its property `directiveVar` to parent property.

This does not work:

```
scope:
    lv1:
        directiveVar: '='
```

And this does not work:

```
scope:
    "lv1.directiveVar": '=myVar'
```

---

**Demo**

This is what works: http://plnkr.co/edit/OClnZ2Cl3BXr60PC2qVP?p=preview

This is what I want to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/tQEHeKOzGjGyplCwUtU2?p=preview

Comment: What is your intent/purpose for needing this; what are you trying to accomplish?  (It may help people give you a better answer).  Also are the children scopes more directives or both directives and controllers?

Comment: Agreed, there isn't enough info here about what you're trying to achieve.  If parentVar/myVar is an object, you should be using '=' instead of '@' to bind to the object and not a string.

Comment: @CorySilva thanks for the feedback. I want to achieve: instead of binding root property of my directive's scope I want to bind a deep property. Updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @CraigSquire thanks for correction. I did mean '=' and not '@'. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code will help.  You can pass in an object and watch its properties or you can nest things in parent/child directives.  Either way adding the "=" will enable two way binding on the entire object.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.directiveVar = {
   level1: {
       greeting: 'Hello'
   }
};
$scope.otherVar = {
    levelA: {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
};
```

**Markup:**

```
<div data-my-parent-directive data-other-var="otherVar">
    <div data-my-directive data-directive-var="directiveVar"></div>
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('MyDirective', [])
.directive('myParentDirective', ['$window',
    function ($window) {
        return{
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope:{
                otherVar: '='
            },
            controller: function($scope, $element) {
                var othis = this;
                this.element = $element;
                this.otherVar = $scope.otherVar;
            }
        };
    }
])
.directive('myDirective', ['$window',
    function ($window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: '?myParentDirective',
            scope: {
                directiveVar: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, elm, attr, myParentDirectiveCtrl) {
                console.log(myParentDirectiveCtrl.otherVar);
                console.log(myDirectiveParentCtrl.otherVar.levelA);
                scope.$watch('directiveVar.level1', function (newValue, oldValue){
                    console.log(newValue, oldValue);
                });
            }
        };
    }
])
```

---

**Edit:**

You could simply do this:

```
<div data-my-parent-directive data-other-var="otherVar">
    <div data-my-directive data-directive-var="directiveVar.level1"></div>
</div>
```

Which is useful when modeling data.  For example:

```
var items = apiService.getItems();
var layers = [...],
$scope.map = {
    points: items,
    layers: layers,
    highAltMap: 'Streets',
    lowAltMap: 'Satellite'
};
```

That said if you are modelling data see this [ng-conf video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg) which I believe the speaker touched on some OO patterns.

**Edit 2:**

You could use a service [like this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oxvPFv9k7DNE1kL5UXWb?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot @CorySilva. I am new to AngularJS, had only 6 month practice. What I wanted to achieve is to bind the child property (directiveVar.level1) without giving the parent access to the whole object (directiveVar). Is there a simple way to declare it in directive's declaration without writing a lot of code?

Comment: thank you for the update. data-directive-var="directiveVar.level1" binds deep property "level1" of the parent scope, which is good. But I need the opposite: to bind deep property of the CHILD scope, something like "lv1.directiveVar": "=var". Sorry it is so hard to explain AngularJS details here, my bad.

Comment: lol no problem; I was just being thick skull'ed.  I suppose for that you would want to make a service and then from your directive watch a function on the service that returns a cached object. If you are able to, share a plunkr of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Updated the post and added two plunks. Thank you for your patience, @CorySilva.

Answer (score 0):

I know date of the question, but...

[Create json object in attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkm58.png)

```js
return {
  scope: {
    date: "=",
    formChange: "=?",
    ngDisabled: "=?",
    deepInclude: "=?"
  },
  ...
```

```html
<user-date-without-current-date date="cv.dateBirthday" deep-include="{cnt:cv.dateBirthday}" form-change="$parent.form_change"></user-date-without-current-date>
```

Is it usefull?